# Hide keyboard on search button click of search bar created by code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created a `search bar` using the code below:

```
 UISearchBar *Search = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0,170 , 50)];
[SearchView addSubview:Search];
```

But when I clicked on the search button the keyboard is not hidden. I have used many methods, like `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` and `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`. Maybe the reason is that my search bar is not attached. I have also used `UISearchBarDelegate` delegate in my .h class and in .m `unload` method:

```
Search.delegate = Self;
```

Can anyone suggest me how to attach my search bar created by code to my View Controller so it should work?

Answer (score 12):

First you need to set `delegate` of your searchBar and then You should use following `delegate` method of `UISearchBar` such like,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Use the `resignFirstResponder`

    -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [candySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

//hide keyboard on searchBarTextDidEndEditing

    - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

 //hide keyboard

    [candySearchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implemented the `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` as following code:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Don't forget to add UISearchBarDelegate in the interface(.h) file.

go on... :)

Comment: I tried this but this method is not called i check it using log ,can you please tell me how i can delegate my search bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the delegate of UISearchBar in ViewDidLoad method as:

```
yourSearchBar.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following delegate function:

```
 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

this is called when user presses the search button. feel free to dismiss your key bored and do whatever you need there

Comment: This method is not called on Search Button clicked ,can you please suggest me what is the problem that it is not called?

Comment: yourSearchBar.delegate = self; As Ashutosh said :0)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it on button action method. When search button is clicked write the following line.

```
(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

This will work.